# django form widget rendering

Tags: python, django, django-forms

hey guys, i want to create a widget that renders a phone field in the following format

```
box - box2 - box3
```

i have tried the different code snippets provided in this same site, however they dont overide the html rendering, which is what i want to do

for example this:

```
class USPhoneNumberMultiWidget(forms.MultiWidget):
"""
A Widget that splits US Phone number input into three <input type='text'> boxes.
"""
def __init__(self,attrs=None):
    widgets = (
        forms.TextInput(attrs={'size':'3','maxlength':'3', 'class':'phone'}),
        forms.TextInput(attrs={'size':'3','maxlength':'3', 'class':'phone'}),
        forms.TextInput(attrs={'size':'4','maxlength':'4', 'class':'phone'}),
    )
    super(USPhoneNumberMultiWidget, self).__init__(widgets, attrs)

def decompress(self, value):
    if value:
        return value.split('-')
    return (None,None,None)

def value_from_datadict(self, data, files, name):
    value = [u'',u'',u'']
    # look for keys like name_1, get the index from the end
    # and make a new list for the string replacement values
    for d in filter(lambda x: x.startswith(name), data):
        index = int(d[len(name)+1:]) 
        value[index] = data[d]
    if value[0] == value[1] == value[2] == u'':
        return None
    return u'%s-%s-%s' % tuple(value)
```

renders an html input of:

```
box|box2|box3
```

so how can i overwrite the rendering so that it renders:

```
box - box2 - box3
```

i would also appreciate any documentation that explains how to create custom widgets, so far i haven't found any

models.py:

```
class Preference(models.Model):
    phone = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True)

class PreferenceForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Preference
        widgets = {
            'phone':USPhoneNumberMultiWidget(attrs={'class':'firstnumberbox', 'id':'firstcellphone', 'name':'firstphone'}),
```

Html rendered:

```
<dt><label for="firstcellphone"> Cell Phone:</label></dt> 
        <dd class="phones"><input name="firstphone" id="firstcellphone_0" maxlength="3" type="text" class="firstnumberbox" size="3" /> - <input name="firstphone" id="firstcellphone_1" maxlength="3" type="text" class="firstnumberbox" size="3" /> - <input name="firstphone" id="firstcellphone_2" maxlength="4" type="text" class="firstnumberbox" size="4" /></dd>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the MultiWidget's format_output method:

```
def format_output(self, rendered_widgets):
        return u'%s - %s - %s' % \
            (rendered_widgets[0], rendered_widgets[1], rendered_widgets[2])
```

There isn't a ton of documentation on custom form widgets. I've only made a couple, and they took a lot of tinkering. Hope that helps!

Comment: thanks for your answer, it worked perfectly when rendering the form , but unfortunately the widget is not submitting anything to the database, ill post my models.py conf in the original question

Comment: @paulo it might help to see the rendered html? Maybe the inputs aren't rendering with an ID?

Comment: In a widget for feet and inches I have on Django Snippets: http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2327/, I didn't have to add any attributes for the id or name, and I ended up using that widget in an inline and regular form without any issues. I'm not certain as to why the values wouldn't be in the POST, but please have a look at that snippet. It might get you in the right direction.

Comment: @james ok ill post it , @brandon will do

Comment: @paulo After Rereading your post i noticed you are using a `PositiveIntegerField` not a `MultiValueField` but your decompress seems to be returning multiple values instead of a positive integer. I have very experience with widgets.

Comment: i got it working now, im using a charfield instead of the positiveintegerfield, i will add validation in the model so that it only takes numbers, thanks all who helped

Comment: @james you mean you have a lot of experience with widgets ? if so could you point to me where can i find more info about them

Comment: @paulo no that should have read: very little -.- Its been bad day for typos.